# Group each row based on dating and count

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have a table already generated, but want to group by counting  the TAILNO by date. But I can only get the total download for each day for all tailno instead for each tailno. Can someone help with this, and there is no way to put column TAILNO in the code as well  the code is :

```
Select CAST(FlightDate AS DATE) AS DATING, count(*) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD
from [base].[dbo].[FlightOperations]

WHERE FlightDate >= CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0, GetDate()- 7), 0),111) 

--- dd means day 

GROUP BY CAST(FlightDate AS DATE)
```

table is :

```
    DATING     TAILNO
--------------------------------------
2016-11-11  024
2016-11-14  024
2016-11-14  024
2016-11-14  024
2016-11-15  024
2016-11-15  024
2016-11-16  024
2016-11-16  024
2016-11-16  024
2016-11-16  024
2016-11-16  024
2016-11-16  024
2016-11-17  024
2016-11-17  024
2016-11-17  024
2016-11-17  024
2016-11-11  030
2016-11-12  030
2016-11-12  030
2016-11-12  030
2016-11-12  030
2016-11-13  030
2016-11-13  030
2016-11-15  030
2016-11-15  030
2016-11-15  030
2016-11-15  030
2016-11-15  030
2016-11-16  030
2016-11-16  030
2016-11-16  030
2016-11-16  030
2016-11-16  030
2016-11-17  030
2016-11-17  030
2016-11-18  030
2016-11-11  057
2016-11-11  057
2016-11-11  057
2016-11-14  057
2016-11-14  057
2016-11-14  057
2016-11-15  057
2016-11-15  057
2016-11-15  057
2016-11-16  057
2016-11-16  057
2016-11-16  057
2016-11-17  057
2016-11-17  057
2016-11-17  057
2016-11-11  058
2016-11-11  058
2016-11-14  058
2016-11-14  058
2016-11-14  058
2016-11-15  058
2016-11-15  058
2016-11-17  058
2016-11-17  058
2016-11-11  125
2016-11-11  125
2016-11-11  125
2016-11-12  125
2016-11-13  125
2016-11-14  125
2016-11-14  125
2016-11-14  125
2016-11-15  125
2016-11-15  125
2016-11-15  125
2016-11-16  125
2016-11-17  125
2016-11-17  125
2016-11-14  185
2016-11-14  185
2016-11-15  185
2016-11-15  185
2016-11-15  185
2016-11-15  185
2016-11-16  185
2016-11-16  185
2016-11-16  185
2016-11-17  185
2016-11-17  185
2016-11-17  185
2016-11-17  185
2016-11-11  190
2016-11-13  190
2016-11-13  190
2016-11-13  190
2016-11-14  190
2016-11-14  190
2016-11-14  190
2016-11-14  190
2016-11-15  190
2016-11-15  190
2016-11-15  190
2016-11-16  190
2016-11-16  190
2016-11-17  190
2016-11-17  190
2016-11-17  190
2016-11-18  190
2016-11-11  216
2016-11-11  216
2016-11-14  216
2016-11-14  216
2016-11-14  216
2016-11-14  216
2016-11-15  216
2016-11-15  216
2016-11-15  216
2016-11-16  216
2016-11-17  216
2016-11-17  216
2016-11-11  237
2016-11-11  237
2016-11-11  237
2016-11-14  237
2016-11-15  237
2016-11-15  237
2016-11-15  237
2016-11-16  237
2016-11-16  237
2016-11-16  237
2016-11-17  237
2016-11-17  237
2016-11-18  237
2016-11-11  241
2016-11-11  241
2016-11-14  241
2016-11-14  241
2016-11-14  241
2016-11-15  241
2016-11-15  241
2016-11-15  241
2016-11-15  241
2016-11-15  241
2016-11-17  241
2016-11-17  241
2016-11-17  241
2016-11-17  241
2016-11-18  241
2016-11-18  241
2016-11-18  241
2016-11-11  250
2016-11-11  250
2016-11-12  250
2016-11-14  250
2016-11-14  250
2016-11-14  250
2016-11-15  250
2016-11-15  250
2016-11-15  250
2016-11-16  250
2016-11-16  250
2016-11-16  250
2016-11-16  250
2016-11-17  250



DATING         TOTALDOWNLOAD   TAIL NO
---------------------------------------------
2016-11-11            1             024        
2016-11-14            3             024
2016-11-15            2             024
2016-11-16            6             024
2016-11-17            4             024

2016-11-11            1             030        
2016-11-12            4            030
2016-11-13            2             030
2016-11-15            5             030
2016-11-16            5             030
2016-11-17            2             030
2016-11-18            1             030
```

Comment: Add tailno to your select and group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this query:

```
Select CAST(FlightDate AS DATE) AS DATING,
       TailNo, count(*) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD
from [base].[dbo].[FlightOperations]
where FlightDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GetDate() - 7) 
group by CAST(FlightDate AS DATE), TailNo
order by CAST(FlightDate AS DATE)
```

This will have one row per date and per `TailNo`.  Notice that I also simplified the date logic in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have changed your code but still use your approach, I commented out the where and cast by because I have separated the table as DATING before, final code is;                                                                    Select  DATING, Tailno,
        count(*) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD
from [base].[dbo].[DASHBOARD_COUNT_EACH] 
----where Fli >= CONVERT(DATE, GetDate() - 7) 
group by CAST(DATING AS DATE), TailNo
order by CAST(DATING AS DATE)